# Performance of Terms Query with many elements

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm planning to use a `Terms Query` with many terms (depending on the case up to 40-50k terms) in all my queries.

These terms will be fetched from another index using lookup as explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup). Elasticsearch takes them internally, so at least they won't go through the wire, but the query itself looks quite heavy.

I was wondering if the query performance will be fine. Anyway I'm planning to do a stress test, but not sure if this is going to escalate well. Someone had experience with these kind of queries or knows how Elasticsearch deals with them internally?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [opened an issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23782) in the Elasticsearch repo about this matter, and as I feared, even using lookup, if used with many terms, this kind of query gets very slow.

Also, I mentioned it in the issue, but I stress tested it and checked it myself:

> filtering with around 20 thousand terms make the query quite slow (more than 500ms).

Comment: Well a second seems ok to me... The question for me is: Is it faster to do 20k queries in sequence than one query with 20k terms? In that case, I would blame the implementation of ES to be pretty stupid.

Comment: It depends on the use case, but for application search, having many users making queries that take a second is way too slow in general. And it's not only about how slow it can be, but about the overhead it brings to the system and how well it's going to scale.

Comment: About doing 20k queries in sequence, I guess that would be slower, because just doing a request, even if it's fast, has a cost. But in this case we can't compare I think, since a Terms query is not equal to making many Term queries, there is more work involved, like filtering the result, etc.

Comment: Hi, do you have data for about *500 terms*? Will that be slow, or very fast? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

Performance after hundreds of terms will degrade fast:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18829

The following is an uber thread that it was originally mentioned in:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11511#issuecomment-224028056

ES will search each term individually across your shards, so as more terms are added, it bogs the cluster down.  As with anything Elasticsearch though, tuning shard amounts (replicas in your case), node counts, and other configuration options might help.  I'd suggest performance testing to know what you're dealing with, but don't expect anything initially.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

I wonder if that happens even using the lookup mechanism... I asked in the issue.